# c# How to queue user requests and respond to them one by one

Tags: c#, com, queue, asp.net-web-api2, task-queue

I have a single instance of an COM service(system application) on my server that my wep api methods call its functions. the com service can process only one request and respond it and after that, process next one.
my idea is queue; queueing user requests and respond to them one by one; but Due to the queue, i don't know how to return response to users;
please help me in implementation of suitable scenario or every other idea.

thanks very much.

Comment: Just create two queues - one for requests, other for responses. Mark your messages with some Guid Id and await in async task for it in response queue. Server will dequeue message, process it and enqueue in response queue, you will dequeue it and complete web api call. By the way, it is called Remote Procedure Call.

Comment: This post may be of some help to you, at least a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506718/how-to-implement-generic-callbacks-using-the-c-sharp-task-parallel-library-and-i

Answer (score 0):

if you keep track in the database for eg the list of queued processes(insert process before start, update process status to done when get back response from your COM service) then you can return that process id and just long poll for the status of that process by that id (api request), maybe also keep showing a dialog or something with the current status while you get done status for the process (we have done something similar on a project)